Where can I find either simulated or observed spectrum single O, B and postAGB star in the wavelength range 1500 A to 9000 Angstrom?
There are stellar spectral libraries such as The Indo-U.S. Library of Coudé Feed Stellar Spectra, MaNGA Stellar Library, The X-Shooter Spectral Library etc. But all of them have spectral coverage above 3000 Angstrom. I need spectrum in the HST F275W band which covers wavelength range between 2300 to 3100 Angstrom. Where can I find it? If it doesn't exist, can I extrapolate the spectra in the libraries above to required wavelengths assuming a blackbody spectrum?

CALSPEC has a number of objects with HST+STIS UV coverage in 1140-10200 Angstrom range; possibly there's something suitable there ?
